# $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^n e^{-n} \frac{n^i}{i!} $

Tags: limits, summation, limits-without-lhopital

Please help me out to find the limit of this series
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^n e^{-n} \frac{n^i}{i!} $$

Upper Limit is easy to find , how to find exact limit

Comment: It's not really a series, because when you go from $n$ to $n + 1$, all the terms that came before change.

Comment: Let's start with you including your work on the problem.

Comment: @amWhy I would prefer it if we were a bit more polite towards people posting questions.

Comment: @user49640  My comment is not any less polite than your original comment.  *So there is nothing that I said* that can be construed as "unpolite".